# Windows Azure Diagnostics Column Explanations

Tags: azure-diagnostics

The default columns recorded by Windows Azure Diagnostics are:

- PartitionKey - ?????
- RowKey - ?????
- Timestamp - The time and date this log was recorded
- EventTickCount - ?????
- DeploymentId - ?????
- Role - The name of the Worker/Web Role this log call was made from
- RoleInstance - The name of the Azure Application Instance this log call was made from
- Level - The level (Debug, Info, Error) of this log
- EventId - ?????
- Pid - ?????
- Tid - ?????
- Message - The actual contents of the log call

I've scoured MSDN for an explanation of what information is recorded in each of these columns. I can infer the meaning of some of them based on the name of the column and the data it contains, but there are some I can't figure out.

What data is recorded in PartitionKey, RowKey, EventTickCount, DeploymentId, EventId, Pid, and Tid?

Answer (score 0):

In order:

PartitionKey / RowKey - Every entity in table storage requires three properties: PartitionKey, RowKey, Timestamp. The PartitionKey is used in partitioning tables across storage nodes. The RowKey is a unique identifier within a given partition.
At the time of this writing, Windows Azure Diagnotics appears to be using the timestamp to generate these values.
References: [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179338.aspx) [2](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2012/10/08/What-PartitionKey-and-RowKey-are-for-in-Windows-Azure-Table-Storage.aspx)

EventTickCount - The timestamp of when the event was generated in ticks.

DeploymentId - the guid assigned to this particular deployment. Used to differentiate one deployment from another.

EventId - the id of the event that was traced. See details about [ETW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information.

Pid - the process id of the process which generated the event.

Tid  - the thread id of the thread which generated the event.